# jQuery Slimscroll on ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, slimscroll

In my web page on one div in which I show table, I have used JQuery Slimscroll plugin. It works fine for Desktop. But for iPad it dosen't work. I have applied slimscroll using following code.

```
<script>
     $('#analyticsContainer').slimScroll({
        height: '250px',
        distance: '3px'
        });

</script>
```

If I want to make this plugin work on ipad also what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no need to implement slimscroll for ipad. As the scrolling in ipad has already a slim bar.

I was able to get this by applying following css to the div.

```
style="height:250px;overflow:auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;"
```

Comment: I combined your code above with code from http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/ to get the same look as the Slimscroll plugin.